# Finding a string in match objects in python

Tags: python, string, find, match

I'd like to find a string in "match objects" in python, but ".find" does not work. Here is my snippet:

```
e_list = []
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    r = re.compile(r".*\.(aaa|bbb)$")
    e_found = r.search(file)
    if e_found is not None:
        e_list.append(e_found.group(0))

e_length = len(e_list);

for num_e in range(e_length):
    if(e_list[num_e].group(0).find('50M') > 0)
        print(e_list[num_e].group(0))
```

... Now `e_list` is like:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='30M.aaa'>,  
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='40M.bbb'>,  
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='50M.aaa'>,  
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='50M.bbb'>,  
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='50M.ccc'>]
```

I'm expecting to have the result:

```
'50M.aaa'  
'50M.bbb'
```

While `e_list[0].group(0)` returns `'30M.aaa'`, `.find` cannot be applied because it's a match object. Then, what should I do?

Comment: For further reading:  The Python 3 "[Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)".

Comment: You should use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) for your regular expressions, to prevent weird interactions with backslashes and string-vs-regex metacharacters:  `r".*\.(aaa|bbb)$"`.  Even though _this_ regex doesn't need it, starting the habit now will save you headaches later.

Comment: To @Kevin J. Chase: Oops, I thought I already put an 'r' in front of the regex, but it was missing. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Python is not your first language, your code smell like Java.

Please do not use `re.compile`, because it is unnecessary. Just use `re.search` or `re.findall`.

And in Python, you can just use:

```
result = re.findall('.*\.(aaa|bbb)$', file)
```

then, `result` is a list, you can print it or use `for... loop` to get every item of it.

As you can also use:

```
result = re.search('.*\.(aaa|bbb)$', file)
```

the result is a group.

Then you should use **result.group(1)** to get the the matched item.

SO, your code can be:

```
e_list = []
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    e_found = re.search(".*\.(aaa|bbb)$", file)

    if e_found:
        e_list.append(e_found.group(1))


for item in e_list:
    if item.find('50M') > 0
        print(item)
```

Comment: Solved by your answer. Actually, e_list.append(e_found.group(0)) gives me what I wanted (the entire file names). Except that, I copied completely yours and it works perfectly. Thank you also for correcting my iteration.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the string begins with `'50M'`, use `str.startswith('50M')`. This will not detect cases where `50M` is the suffix (`test.50M`).

```
if e_list[num_e].startswith('50M'):
    print(e_list[num_e])
```

If the suffix is a legitimate place to find the `50M`, using `in` is much cleaner than `.find('50M') > 0`.

```
if '50M' in e_list[num_e]:
```

Comment: It didn't work. After reading Kingname's answer, I noticed that the last part should have been:
if(e_list[num_e].find('50M') > 0):
    print(e_list[num_e])

Comment: @IanHacker Ah, I see. I have updated my answer to be correct - the ways I describe will be much cleaner and more specific than `.find()`.